# Is it okay for letting agency to deny me viewing for not telling them my employer name and how long I had been in a profession?

Tags: united-kingdom, gdpr, rental-property

Is it okay for a letting agency to ask me these questions ?

1. What is the name of company I work for ?
2. The property I am renting at the present is through agency or a landlord?
3. How long I have been working as a software developer?

They also asked me for how much I am earning and some other questions which I answered. When I further inquired they told me that until I answer these question they won't let me view the property and answers will be used for pre-screening.

Is it okay for letting agency to deny me viewing for not telling them my employer name and how long I had been in a profession ?

I know if I liked the property and for referencing they may need letter from my employer but I wasn't at this stage yet.

Comment: [Art. 13(1)(c,d)](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-13-gdpr/) requires the company to explain the legal basis and legitimate interests of the processing. You should have gotten that information, otherwise you can [ask](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-15-gdpr/) for it. Based on the answer they give, it would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: @wimh they said pre screening purposes, but I am not sure if it's allowed or not

Comment: I would say that is not specific enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers don't quite spell it out, so I will.

There is no law in the UK requiring landlords or their agents to show a property to all parties interested - refusal to show a property may however in some cases fall under discrimination laws, so that might be something you can pursue if you feel the refusal is due to your gender, race or sexual orientation.

While they may have to justify their data collection under the GDPR, that is entirely separate to their refusal to show the property to you.

Answer (score 0):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

I don't know what the law is in the UK on this matter. In the US, an agency can and some will ask such questions, and use the answers to determine who to show the property to. Essentially, they don't want to bother showing it to people who are not going to qualify as tenants. Amount and stability of income are considered legitimate factors for a landlord or landlord's agent to use in deciding who to consider as a tenner. Source of income goes to stability. So does length of time in your current profession.

Answer (score 0):

There are no grounds to argue "discrimination" in this case... be careful with that.
It is a private service being rendered by a private company and they may define their rules which can easily be supported by the argumentation of efficiency and cost (over non-effective work).

The grounds for such processing is Consent, for any Legitimate Interest argumentation would collide with your Legitimate Interest to your Privacy.

Make sure they explain WHY they need that specific Personal Data, if they do not explain, then you have grounds to present a complaint... if they do, you may either decide to provide the Data and get the service/ or denial of Service.

If they deny you the service, make sure to submit a request for Data Erasure, since there is no point in them maintaining your Personal Data... even if they agree to show you the house, once the process has ended, submit a request for Data Erasure... they no longer need your Data.

This is not "really" GDPR, yet you should not leave Data laying around...

Answer (score -1):

Scope and purpose.

As David Siegel mentioned they may have their reasons.

The point (under GDPR) is that in order to collect such Personal Data they must explain to you WHY do they need it.

If they just say "we need this", then your Consent is not "enlighten" meaning you have not agreed to the specific requirements, hence deemed invalid (even if you have provided Consent).

If they are not asking for your Consent (or a contract) then they have no Lawful Base for processing your Personal Data, even if their Terms of Service do so detail.

They may, however, refuse to render you the service if you do not provide the information... it's "their game".

I am able to understand (empirically) why they are asking for the type of Personal Data that you have mentioned, it "makes sense" where they want to "qualify leads" and not waste time showing a house to someone who does not gather the requirements to rent it.

Nevertheless, they must inform you about "scope" and "purpose" and collect your explicit consent once having done so... under GDPR that is.

Comment: There can be other lawful bases under the GDPR than consent for collecting and processing personal data. Under GDPR Art 6 (1)(f)  "processing is necessary for the purposes of the legitimate interests pursued by the controller or by a third party" is a lawful basis, and it obviates any issue of consent when it applies. Under Art 13(1)(c) the purpose must still be supplied to the subject, and under 13(1)(d) the legitimate interest, if that is the basis, must be stated.

Comment: Legitimate Interest needs to be subject to an Impact Assessment and in this case, it collides with the Legitimate Interest of the Data Subject to his Privacy, hence not applicable.